# Spring controller disable parameters from body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api

I have a spring endpoint that looks like this:

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/test",
        consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE},
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public TestDTO test(TestDTO testDTO){
    return testDTO;
}
```

with the DTO looking like this:

```
public class TestDTO {

    @ApiModelProperty(
            name = "sample",
            value = "sample",
            dataType = "String",
            example = "shhhhhh"
    )
    private String sample;

}
```

so obviously, a curl request like this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8081/test' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'sample=testReturnData'
```

returns

```
{
    "sample": "testReturnData"
}
```

But, if I add a parameter like this

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8081/test?sample=doNotIncludeThis' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'sample=testReturnData'
```

I get a response back like this:

```
{
    "sample": "doNotIncludeThis,testReturnData"
}
```

I only want spring to grab data from the body, not the param. I want the response to look like

```
{
    "sample": "testReturnData"
}
```

The `@RequestBody` annotation does not work with `x-www-form-url-encoded` format (which is the format I need), because it will return a 415.

Comment: I think you might need to understand a bit better about the HTTP specification. Accordingly to it query parameters and content **are not** mutually exclusive for an HTTP server that accepts POST or PUT requests. So I don't think you can do this directly without building some sort of filter that checks the URI/URL

Comment: Jorge, you might be right about this, but say if I accept an additional parameter @RequestParam Map<String,String> receivedParameters in my controller, receivedParameters will only populate with "doNotIncludeThis", meaning spring can differentiate between the body and params. Are there any annotations that block additional params or something of the sort?

Comment: Disagree about your experiment if you have a parameter that is a MAP, it means the same key `sample` can not be used twice, therefore whatever is the last parameter processed is the valid one (try sending two different values). As per the HTTP specification all parameters are processed and since you are sending two of the same it is likely translating it into an array, therefore returning the comma delimited value. Now whether spring specifically allow you to do the distinction of request parameter / request body preventing one or another I really don't know. Never seeing it done before.

Comment: Due to the length of my response, please see this controlc link (similar to pastebin) https://controlc.com/bbb7d22b

As you can see, the @RequestParam grabs only the paramters

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the wrong solution.  Why do you get a 415 when you use `@RequestBody`?  This is not standard behavior.

You see, Spring doesn't recognize the body of a request when `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is used.  The [Spring documentation states](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.0/reference/html/web.html#filters-http-put):

> The spring-web module provides FormContentFilter to intercept HTTP PUT, PATCH, and DELETE requests with a content type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, read the form data from the body of the request, and wrap the ServletRequest to make the form data available through the ServletRequest.getParameter*() family of methods.

In order to configure Spring properly, you need to configure Spring's `FormContentFilter`.  This should be enabled by default, but you can make sure it is by setting it in the `application.properties`.

```
spring.mvc.formcontent.putfilter.enabled=true
```

Comment: Understood, but by that logic, there is pretty much no difference between a parameter and a body in form-url-encoded? How does a client pass securely a secret (say a token)? Additionally, as a parameter, this could get logged, which gets posed as a security risk.

Comment: That is what I was trying to say to you. It is not responsibility of the **server** to allow what a client do or doesn't do, it can only process it. Like I also mentioned you will need to create a filter and check whether your end point allows querystring parameters and send an http error back if not.

Comment: If you are looking for security functions, such as validating a secret, then you need to implement a new filter along your filter chain.  I don't want to get into the how, as that can be easily googled, but you will basically need to create a class that extends the Filter you need (in most cases this is the `GenericFilterBean`), and then add that bean to the `SecurityFilterChain` in your Configuration file.  I can update my answer with more detail if needed.